# C++ - Win32 API for Extracting .zip

Tags: c++, winapi, zip

I've been needing to extract a .zip file programmaticly  and was wondering if there was an API that Win32 has to extract these types of files. I seen there is a Compress/Decompress but I have noticed that's for compressing the raw bytes instead of actually extracting it to a folder on the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native Win32 API for working with `.zip` files (or any other archive type).  You have to use a third-party library (there are plenty of open-source and commercial libraries available), or read the ZIP spec and write your own logic from scratch.

Comment: Although not specifically documented, you can use the [IShellFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775075.aspx) interface to enumerate (and extract) files from a ZIP archive. Support is limited, though (e.g. no encryption).

Comment: @IInspectable yes, but only because it is part of Explorer's functionality to treat zip files as virtual folders in its UI. It is an implementation detail, not a published API meant for public use.

Comment: I'll have to disagree here. As is always the case with COM, you don't get much documentation on top of the interface. No matter the root cause, if you can construct an `IShellFolder` interface from a ZIP archive, you should be free to use it. Had Microsoft never intended this to be used outside of *File Explorer*'s implementation, surely they could have kept the implementation private. As long as your code is prepared to handle errors, using an implementation through a documented interface does not constitute relying on undocumented implementation details.